# How to reduce webpack dev server rebuild time

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm developing a Javascript game that uses large 3d assets locally. I require those assets with webpack, like:

```
require('../../assets/models/house.obj')
```

As you can see, doing things like this gives me a large initial bundle and large initial build time:

```
[0]           main-ad421c4138968fe0a8ae.js    14.8 MB       0  [emitted]  main
[0] webpack built ad421c4138968fe0a8ae in 26610ms
```

I'm OK with the large build time, but the real issue is the rebuild time using the dev server.

```
[1] [piping] File src/Game.js has changed, reloading.
[0] webpack built 80f5c6c75e347304002c in 10534ms
```

It takes 10-20 seconds to rebuild the bundle, and even longer to reach the browser. I'd like to reduce this time if possible.

I've tried ignoring my assets folder entirely:

```
new webpack.IgnorePlugin( /assets\/*/ ),
```

But as you might guess, this means I can no longer `require()` an asset by its loacl path, which is basically the whole point of using webpack.

I've also tried using the [webpack watch ignore plugin](https://github.com/christophercliff/watch-ignore-webpack-plugin) to ignore my assets folder, and node modules:

```
new WatchIgnorePlugin([
    path.resolve( __dirname, '../assets/models/' ),
    path.resolve( __dirname, '../node_modules/' )
]),
```

However this doesn't reduce the build time either. I [filed a bug](https://github.com/christophercliff/watch-ignore-webpack-plugin/issues/5) because it appears the plugin doesn't actually do anything at all.

Comment: If your assets don't change between rebuilds AND (I assume since they are assets), there is no js code that depends on anything else of your app - only your app depends on them, couldn't you make [multiple entry chunks](https://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html#running-multiple-entry-points) ? (In your case a first entry with your assets that will never reload, as long as you don't change them - and a second with the code of your game)

Comment: @topheman is that possible considering my main entry chunk would still have to require all the assets? Wouldn't webpack still bundle them into A?

Comment: I added a separate entry chunk that includes all my large assets in it, still huge build times

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way I've found to significantly reduce hot reload time is to use Webpack's odd "DllPlugin". Basically it builds a static file with all your third party dependencies in it, so Webpack never touches those dependencies again during hot reload.

I wrote up everything I currently know about it [here](https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example/issues/616#issuecomment-228956242).